# What Do I Do if Someone is Systematically Downvoting my Answers?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, users, down-votes

I hope this is the right place to post this question!

I just found that, about two hours ago, eleven answers of mine were suddenly downvoted, including some from several months ago. I can only assume that someone is upset with me and is just systematically downvoting my material.

What should I do, if anything, about this? Can I assume that this will be automatically picked up and removed? Should I just ignore it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you've been a victim of [serial downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).  There is a script that runs (I think nightly) to detect and reverse voting anomolies like this, so my guess is that you'll get your votes back tomorrow.  It seems unlikely that eleven different people simultaneously developed aversions to one of your answers.

Comment: +1 Also worth noting that scripts exist to prevent serial upvoting too.

Comment: It worked. From [@LazerA's reputation log](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1216/lazera?tab=reputation): `+22  12 hours ago  reversal  Serial downvoting reversed`

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to come back and mention it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem @LazerA.  Glad to see it got fixed.